# Problem with WKWebView in Thumbnail Extension

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, thumbnails

Developing a thumbnail extension for a custom file type in my iOS app. I am using a WKWebView to render an HTML string and then capturing a snapshot of the WKWebView to use for the thumbnail image. Works great on simulators. However, not completing when run on a real device.

[Here is example code that one can use to duplicate the crash.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cb8cqawfimu6v1/thumbnailextensioncrash.zip?dl=1)

Here is the code:

```swift
    let thumbFileView = WKWebView(frame: frame)
    thumbFileView.navigationDelegate = self
    thumbFileView.pageZoom = scale
    thumbFileView.layoutIfNeeded()
    thumbFileView.loadHTMLString(thumbFile.asHtml, baseURL: nil)
```

Thumbnail image is perfect on simulator, but on real device there is a crash in the logs:

```
2020-12-08 11:01:30.191156-0700 ThumbFileThumbnail[35519:906998] [] networkd_settings_setup_notify_watch notify_register_dispatch(com.apple.system.networkd.settings) [status 9] failed
2020-12-08 11:01:30.205445-0700 ThumbFileThumbnail[35519:906998] [] networkd_settings_setup_notify_watch notify_register_dispatch(com.apple.system.networkd.settings) [status 9] failed, dumping backtrace:
        [arm64] libnetcore-2288.42.1
    0   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001a2ce1658 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 116
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001a2c6ffdc C67A2D71-4415-3F82-9399-65C3956520AE + 5832668
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001a2c6f6c0 C67A2D71-4415-3F82-9399-65C3956520AE + 5830336
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001a2a777d0 C67A2D71-4415-3F82-9399-65C3956520AE + 3766224
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001a2c26408 nw_path_create_evaluator_for_endpoint_no_evaluate + 544
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001a2c25ee0 nw_path_create_evaluator_for_endpoint + 84
    6   Network                             0x00000001b5a063e0 2FB89D76-EA38-3B43-BCD1-E0C7EE9B9012 + 1180640
    7   Network                             0x00000001b5a058b4 2FB89D76-EA38-3B43-BCD1-E0C7EE9B9012 + 1177780
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18c0280 6C143C51-288F-3CD0-84DD-17B9A0AAEE62 + 397952
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18642f4 6C143C51-288F-3CD0-84DD-17B9A0AAEE62 + 21236
    10  Network                             0x00000001b5a05888 2FB89D76-EA38-3B43-BCD1-E0C7EE9B9012 + 1177736
    11  NetworkExtension                    0x00000001b268a4e4 4F673F38-E238-37C5-9B26-2A540CB429B9 + 357604
    12  WebKit                              0x00000001ad9a8334 19789FD9-1098-37B7-B639-9E4F0EB867D6 + 2847540
    13  WebKit                              0x00000001ada0bdc8 19789FD9-1098-37B7-B639-9E4F0EB867D6 + 3255752
    14  WebKit                              0x00000001ada0ba20 19789FD9-1098-37B7-B639-9E4F0EB867D6 + 3254816
    15  WebKit                              0x00000001ad6fda9c 19789FD9-1098-37B7-B639-9E4F0EB867D6 + 51868
    16  ThumbFileThumbnail                  0x00000001044f4ee8 $s18ThumbFileThumbnail0abC9GeneratorC04loadaB4View3for2in5scaleSo05WKWebF0CAA0aB0V_So6CGRectV12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVtF + 704
    17  ThumbFileThumbnail                  0x00000001044f42a4 $s18ThumbFileThumbnail0abC9GeneratorC20provideSnapshotImage3for5scale5frame10completionyAA0aB0V_12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVSo6CGRectVySo7UIImageCSgctFyycfU_ + 204
    18  ThumbFileThumbnail                  0x00000001044f44e0 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 52
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18bf298 6C143C51-288F-3CD0-84DD-17B9A0AAEE62 + 393880
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a18c0280 6C143C51-288F-3CD0-84DD-17B9A0AAEE62 + 397952
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a186f05c 6C143C51-288F-3CD0-84DD-17B9A0AAEE62 + 65628
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1c075d0 96F8386D-D88A-3C89-A323-A17975C3317F + 632272
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1c01a78 96F8386D-D88A-3C89-A323-A17975C3317F + 608888
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a1c00b90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    25  Foundation                          0x00000001a2e1e7f8 F1BC26A1-F5BB-36F7-A65A-D5F232DBF902 + 30712
    26  Foundation                          0x00000001a2e4f964 F1BC26A1-F5BB-36F7-A65A-D5F232DBF902 + 231780
    27  libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001e76af1c4 E3552D23-ADFB-36FE-B7D0-B23090553C49 + 86468
    28  libxpc.dylib                        0x00000001e76b13bc xpc_main + 176
    29  Foundation                          0x00000001a2e51b78 F1BC26A1-F5BB-36F7-A65A-D5F232DBF902 + 240504
    30  PlugInKit                           0x00000001cefc28c0 __PLUGINKIT_CALLING_OUT_TO_CLIENT_SUBSYSTEM_FOR_BEGINUSING__ + 35616
    31  PlugInKit                           0x00000001cefc2530 __PLUGINKIT_CALLING_OUT_TO_CLIENT_SUBSYSTEM_FOR_BEGINUSING__ + 34704
    32  PlugInKit                           0x00000001cefc2cb8 __PLUGINKIT_CALLING_OUT_TO_CLIENT_SUBSYSTEM_FOR_BEGINUSING__ + 36632
    33  ExtensionKit                        0x00000001a5f514e0 EXExtensionMain + 80
    34  Foundation                          0x00000001a2f8d1cc NSExtensionMain + 192
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001a18df588 E31C0887-C999-3047-9B80-203248EC2396 + 5512
```

From setting a runtime issues breakpoint, the offending line of code is:

```swift
    thumbFileView.loadHTMLString(thumbFile.asHtml, baseURL: nil)
```

[image: runtime issues breakpoint]

Since the html contains an image URL, this seems to point to some limitation that iOS is placing on the thumbnail extension that is blocking it from accessing the network. This is evident from the crash log and from the stack at the time of the issue.

I've studied Apple's documentation of NSExtensionAttributes and can't find anything that would address this permission issue.

Here are the NSExtensionAttributes for the thumbnail extension:

```xml
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>QLSupportedContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.raywenderlich.RazeThumb.ThumbFile</string>
            </array>
            <key>QLThumbnailMinimumDimension</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
```

Welcome any ideas on how to get this working on real devices and not just simulator.

Comment: Can you provide demo project including test data? Thanks

Comment: An example would help. I do something similar and it works fine for me on devices.

Comment: You should at least provide the HTML file. In your words, your app crashed because there was a image link in the HTML file. So files without a image link worked?

Comment: I've added a download link to try out the program. To see the crash, you must first run the app to load it to your device, then select the thumbnail extension and run it. Scroll down to "greenthumb.thumb", the custom file type to see the crash.